# Question about a curve that doesn't touch the origin.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

> Let $\alpha : I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a curve such that $\alpha (t)\neq\underline{0}$, $\forall t\in I$. Let $t_{0}$ a point such that $\alpha (t_{0})$ is as near as possible to $\underline{0}$. Suppose that $\alpha '(t_{0})\neq\underline{0}$. Prove that $\alpha (t_{0})$ is perpendicular to $\alpha ' (t_{0})$.

I though that, because of the hypotesis, $<\alpha(t_{0}),\alpha(t_{0})> = c\in\mathbb{R}-\lbrace0\rbrace$. So

$$\frac{d}{dt} <\alpha(t_{0}),\alpha ' (t_{0})> = <\alpha '(t_{0}),\alpha(t_{0})>+<\alpha (t_{0}), \alpha '(t_{0})>=2<\alpha(t_{0}),\alpha '(t_{0})> = 0$$

So, because $\alpha '(t_{0})\neq\underline{0}$ we have the assertion.

I have some doubts because I didn't use the fact that $\alpha(t_{0})$ is the most near to the origin. Can someome explain to me if I did something wrong? Thanks before.

Comment: Your proof does not work. Since $\langle \alpha(t_0), \alpha'(t_0)\rangle$ is constant the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}\langle \alpha(t_0), \alpha'(t_0)\rangle = 0$ already. Instead, you should write $2\langle \alpha(t_0), \alpha'(t_0)\rangle = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t = t_0} \|\alpha(t)\|^2$ and use the condition on $\alpha(t_0)$ to argue that this derivative is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track!

Define the function $|| \alpha(t) || : I \to \mathbb{R}$. Since $\alpha(t_0)$ is closest point to the origin, it means that $||\alpha(t)||$ attains its minimum at $t_0$. That implies that its derivative at $t = t_0$ is zero, i.e.
$$ \frac{d}{dt} ||\alpha(t) ||^2 \; \Big|_{t = t_0}  = 2 \cdot \langle \alpha(t_0), \alpha'(t_0) \rangle = 0$$
which means that $\alpha(t_0)$ and $\alpha'(t_0)$ are perpendicular.

Aside: To get the left and right brackets for inner product, use `\langle` and `\rangle` - it makes your stuff look way better.

Comment: Why for the minimum the derivative is zero? Is it a Theorem?

Comment: lol I wrote a bullshit. I didn't think that it's a critical point ahahah

Comment: It's called Fermat's Theorem (calculus).

Comment: The expression $\frac{d}{dt}\|\alpha(t)\| |_{t = t_0}$ should be $\frac{d}{dt} \|\alpha(t)\|^2 |_{t = t_0}$.

Comment: @kobe You are right, thanks for the catch!